# Multiple BufferedImage transfer socket

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedimage

I am trying to transfer multiple gif images as BufferedImages from client to server. But once a single image starts to transfer ,the client socket closes. The code I have tried is as follows

Server

```
    private void connect() {
        int noOfFiles, w, h;
        BufferedImage bi;
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5223);
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
            noOfFiles = dis.readInt();
            System.out.println("Total Files: " + noOfFiles);
            dis.close();
            s.close();
            ServerSocket ssa = new ServerSocket(5225);
            Socket sa = ssa.accept();
            InputStream isa = sa.getInputStream();
            for (int x = 0; x < noOfFiles; x++) {
                File imgFile = new File("D:\\aa\\" + x);
                bi = ImageIO.read(isa);
                w = bi.getWidth();
                System.out.println(w);
                h = bi.getHeight();
                if (bi.getType() != BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB) {
                    BufferedImage bi1 = new BufferedImage(w, h,
 BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                    Graphics g = bi1.getGraphics();
                    g.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
                }
                ImageIO.write(bi, "GIF", imgFile);                
            }
            sa.close();
            ssa.close();            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Client

```
 private void connect() {
        Image i;
        BufferedImage bi = null;
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 5223);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            File fol = new File("D:\\images\\red");
            File[] files = fol.listFiles();
            dos.writeInt(files.length);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();          
            Socket ss = new Socket("localhost", 5225);
            for (File f : files) {                
                i = ImageIO.read(f);
                bi = (BufferedImage) i;
                ImageIO.write(bi, "GIF", ss.getOutputStream());                                
            }
            ss.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the exceptions I get are as follows:

Server

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PortScanNew.ImgTrnsfrSvr.connect(ImgTrnsfrSvr.java:54)
    at PortScanNew.ImgTrnsfrSvr.main(ImgTrnsfrSvr.java:33)
Java Result: 1
```

Client

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageOutputStream.flushBefore(FileCacheImageOutputStream.java:255)
    at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.flush(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:825)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.doWrite(ImageIO.java:1615)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1578)
    at PortScanNew.ImgTrnClnt.connect(ImgTrnClnt.java:44)
    at PortScanNew.ImgTrnClnt.main(ImgTrnClnt.java:26)
```

I looked through many examples but I didn't get any idea from them. Any suggestions?

Comment: `ImageIO` closes the `Socket`, you can't use it...Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505406/java-tcp-can-only-retrieve-image-once/18509880#18509880) of a possible way around it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried creating sockets for each file and closing them at the end, still same result.

Comment: `ImageIO` doesn't play nice with the sockets at either end. Take a look at the linked example for a possible solution

Comment: Why do you have multiple ServerSocket ? Only 1 serversocket is enough do handle multiple clients.

Comment: Well you haven't told us what line of your code `ImgTrnsfrSvr.java:54)` is, or `PortScanNew.ImgTrnClnt.connect(ImgTrnClnt.java:44)`, but you don't need `ImageIO` just to transfer a file over a socket from client to server. Just copy the bytes. As you're keeping the socket open, you'll also have to transfer the file length before each file, and you'll have to adjust your server code accordingly.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I understand your program but I have 3 doubts.      1) You used byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]. Does this mean you have assumed that the image you are going to receive can be only around 1 MB or does this mean something else? Don't mistake me but I don't get that line.                                                  2)You convert everything to byte[] and send it to server, isn't there any other alternative?                                       3) Won't converting objects to byte[] and transferring them take more time?

Comment: @Parthe (1) 1024 is 1KB, not 1MB. (2) His code reads into this buffer *in a loop.* There is no presumption about the file size. (3) Why are you asking for an alternative to working code? (4) No objects are being converted to bytes. Bytes are being read, and bytes are being written.

Comment: @EJP ImgTrnsfrSvr.java:54 is w = bi.getWidth(); and ImgTrnClnt.java:44 is ImageIO.write(bi, "GIF", ss.getOutputStream());

Comment: @Parthe So obviously `bi` is null. So obviously the preceding `ImageIO.read()` failed for some reason.

Comment: @EJP ya sorry its a typo i know its 1 kb. If there is no presumption about file size what is that 1024 and why is that specifically 1024. I have seen this in many programs, that is why I am curious about that 1024. Ok bytes are being read and written my question is that won't it increase the transfer time? if no is your answer why is it so?

Comment: @MadProgrammer You have sent a command every time when you want to fetch image. Do you think this be efficient and a fast process when fetching image file continuously?

Comment: @Parthe A buffer is a buffer. Some people use 1024. I use 8192. (2) Simply transferring bytes is the fastest possible technique. Compared to what you're doing, which is converting the bytes to an Image and back, it is orders of magnitude faster, and it is baffling that you can think otherwise. (3) If you're going to just argue with everybody I don't see the point of posting here at all. You could always *try* it. It's not as though you already have working code.

Comment: @EJP What do you mean by that? Does that mean buffer size is 1kb? if so, does that mean buffer can only hold 1kb at a time? I am not arguing just curious in getting to know what is what

Comment: @Parthe Of course that's what it means. How could it possibly hold more?

Comment: @EJP I am new to java sockets and buffers so I am trying to learn as much as possible. So the buffer holds and transfers 1kb at a time. Am I getting it right?

Comment: @Parthe This is really not the place to explain a standard Java copy loop to you. I suggest you study the code, specifically the way the return value of the `read()` method is used in the `write()` method.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for your help. I will examine the code. Just one more doubt, the code Madprogrammer has given receives images on the client side. I want to receive images on server socket side, so should i create a new socket and accept it every time I send an image?

Comment: @Parthe Just as a buffer is a buffer, a socket is a socket. Once you have a socket on each side it doesn't matter who is the server and who is the client. You should be perfectly able to transpose the code accordingly.

Comment: @EJP I get it now thanks. Since he used byte[] to transfer data, the connection doesn't end whereas in my case ImageIO closes the connection. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Parthe That's exactly what he told you two hours ago in the very first comment here.

Comment: @Parthe 1- No, this is just the buffer size, I'm sending 1mb chunks at a time through the pipe until it's read the entire file. 2- Not really, the only other choice you would have would be to write the image to a file and stream the `InputStream` of the file to the `OutputStream` of the `Socket`, `Socket`'s aren't easy. 3- As compared to what?  What do you think you're sending down the pipe anyway?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the help I got it and tried some new code but there is a problem with that. Should I post it here or should I start a new thread for that?