# Multiple image files on a TCP socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, inputstream, javax.imageio

I am trying to send multiple images on a TCP socket.

The following code is running fine without a problem: the client and server exchange a greeting. Then the client is sending 
a single image file which the server receives.

Client side:

```
...        
try      {
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket(serverName, port);
    DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("Heard from server: "+in.readUTF());

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    out.writeUTF("Hello from " + clientSocket.getLocalSocketAddress());

    BufferedImage bimg;

//    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)  {
    bimg = ImageIO.read(new File("flowers.jpg"));  
    ImageIO.write(bimg,"jpg",clientSocket.getOutputStream());   
    out.flush(); 
    System.out.println("Image sent");
//    }
    clientSocket.close();
  } catch(Exception e) { ... }
```

Server side:

```
...
Socket socket=null;
DataInputStream din=null;
DataOutputStream dout=null;
...
socket = serverSocket.accept();  
din=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
dout=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

for (;;)  {  
    try  {

        dout.writeUTF("ImageReceiver here at your service: ");

        System.out.println("from the client: "+din.readUTF());
        BufferedImage img;

//for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        img=ImageIO.read(socket.getInputStream());   
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(timeStamp+"img.png"));
        System.out.println("Image received...");
//} 
        socket.close();
        break;
   }
  catch(Exception e) {  .... }
 }
```

When I uncomment the 2*2 lines in the above and thus send&receive images in a loop, I am getting an exception that the image is null:

the server is receiving the 1st image fine without errors. However, after that, it is not 
seeing the input stream as an image. The call to ImageIO.read() at

```
img=ImageIO.read(socket.getInputStream());
```

is returning null and

```
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File(timeStamp+"img.png"));
```

is throwing the exception.

The client process is running fine without any errors.

Is this a matter of managing the I/O buffers?

Where to look to fix it?

TIA.

//=======================================

I'm getting the same error when I'm sending 2 images: the first image is transmitted&received fine.

The client is sending the second image as the last thing before it closes. However, the server isn't seeing the second one as an image. After the first image is transmitted, there's nothing in the server-socket's input buffer but the second image.

Comment: You don't need ImageIO to read a file and send it over a socket, or *vice versa.* Just send the bytes.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but perhaps `ImageIO.read()` reads until the end of the stream or grabs some additional data. In that case you could change your protocol to convert the image to a `byte[]` first, send the data length and data itself, then read only the necessary data into a `byte[]` on the receiving end and construct images from that. That way `ImageIO.read()` won't take more than you want it to. Don't quote me on this. Somebody correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @EJP You would if you wanted to take advantage of encoding it to a smaller image format (e.g. PNG) for transfer.

Comment: @EJP why isn't the above working at the first place. I don't even know where the problem is.

Comment: @JasonC I'm flushing the output buffer on the client before sending the next image. there's nothing on the client output but the image.

Comment: @user3401132 I'm talking about the receiving end. Perhaps `ImageIO.read()` reads more than its fair share of data, thus reading (and discarding) some or all of the following images in the stream after the first one is read.

Comment: @JasonC: see my edit in Q.

Comment: `ImageIO` does not work well with sockets.  The write process requires the `OutputStream` to be closed before all the contents are finalised and it has a habit of closing the streams when it's done...If you really HAVE to use `ImageIO` for the process for some reason, take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505406/java-tcp-can-only-retrieve-image-once/18509880#18509880), although, all it does it converts the image to a `ByteArray` for transport across the socket...

Comment: @JasonC You would indeed, but there is no evidence of that being either attempted or required in the question. I do see a converstion from JPEG to IMG at the server, which could be either a requirement or a mistake, but the client isn't doing any such thing, and indeed he is doing something ill-advised, i.e. re-encoding a JPEG.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - done it in bytes. thx for the useful note.

Answer (score 0):

ImageIO closes the input stream after reading the image.It needs to be created again and again for reading multiple images using ImageIO.createImageInputStream().
 You can see it here-https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream-

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code. This code sends data in bytes.

client (Sender):

```
try {
        int port = 8989; // Your Server port number
        Socket sender = new Socket("Server IP", port);
        int count,i=0;

        byte[] data = new byte[1024]; // Here provide size of your file
        FileInputStream fileStream = null;
        BufferedInputStream fileBuffer = null;
        OutputStream out = sender.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = sender.getInputStream();

        while (i < 10) {

            fileStream = new FileInputStream("fileURL");
            fileBuffer = new BufferedInputStream(fileStream);

            // Sending file data in bytes
            while ((count = fileBuffer.read(data)) > 0) {
                System.out.println("Data Sent : " + count);
                out.write(data, 0, count);
                out.flush();
            }

            // Waiting for response
            while (in.available() <= 0) {
            }
            if (in.read() == 0) {
                System.out.println("File Sent Successfully");
                i++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("File Not Sent Successfully");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Server (Receiver):

```
try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);

        // Waiting for client
        Socket receiveSocket = server.accept();
        InputStream in = receiveSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = receiveSocket.getOutputStream();
        int count, cnt = 10, i = 0;

        // cnt will be total number of files
        while (i < cnt) {
            byte data[] = new byte[1024]; // Provide file size here
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("fileURL");
            BufferedOutputStream fileBuffer = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOut);

            // Waiting till client is sending the file
            while (in.available() <= 0) {
            }
            // Receiving byte data and storing it in the file
            while ((count = in.read(data)) > 0) {
                fileBuffer.write(data, 0, count);
                System.out.println("Data Received : " + count);
                fileBuffer.flush();
            }
            // Notify client that you received that file successfully
            out.write(0);

            // Close all streams
            in.close();
            out.close();
            fileBuffer.close();
            fileOut.close();
            i++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thx - but looking to sort out on the above code. have one on bytes already.

Comment: Ya but this will not generate any exception also. I have tried this.

Comment: There is no necessity to 'here provide the size of your file'. 1024 or indeed any positive value will work for the buffer size. The `available()` loop that waits for the response is literally a waste of time and also a misuse of the CPU. Just removing it would fix both problems. The following `read()` will block until data arrives anyway. You are also printing 'data sent' before you send it, which is to say the least misleading. Your application protocol that sends another byte after the image isn't necessary.