# How to take Screenshot in Java using IP address

Tags: java, ip, screenshot

Here i am using Java to get Screenshot and I am using this code.

```
Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(d);
            Robot r1 = new Robot();
            BufferedImage bi = r1.createScreenCapture(r);
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", new File("/home/kishan/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication1/src/javaapplication1/screen.png"));
```

but if i have Some Ip address then how to take Screenshot of that particular IP machine.?
lets say I have Local Server and Some Node connected to that so how to take that Screen shot for one user of that server from server it self ? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: run your app on that machine as well, make a socket connection to signal it to take screenshot and stream it back to server

Comment: You need some kind of program on the machine which is capable of handling that request and sending the result back to, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505406/java-tcp-can-only-retrieve-image-once/18509880#18509880) - this is VERY basic and needs to cleaned up, but should give you an idea of what needs to be done...

Comment: okey @MadProgrammer i am trying that if there is any query i will ask u. :)

Comment: but if there is multiple client then what?? it will open for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after doing a lot of research. i conclude this things. 
What i have done is I have Created A jar which is taking Normal Photo and saving at particular server.

and i am running jar from remote pc so there is no need of taking IP for the PC.

Answer (score 0):

In your client side its you have to develop that whenever a screen shoot is request from server, client take a screenshot and send it to server

suppose

server send a message to client =="screenshot"

client recieve message and check wheather message is screenshot if yes capture a screenshot and send it to server..

http://www.coderanch.com/t/370601/java/java/RUN-COMMAND-REMOTE-PC

Comment: But what if there is multiple client. and i need to make that if server select that particular address then it should capture that screen