# send screenshots over network

Tags: java, swing, sockets, screenshot

I am trying to send continuous screenshots to another PC on same network.

I googled it also but i didn't find things relevant to me. 
Below is my code of sender and receiver. Problem is only first image is being received and then struck.
If i turn on JFrame then not a single image is updating in JPanel. Please help me :-(

**imagesender.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class imagesender
{
    imagesender()throws Exception
    {
        Socket soc=new Socket("127.0.0.1",5555);
        OutputStream os=soc.getOutputStream();
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                Dimension dim=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                Rectangle rec=new Rectangle(dim);
                Robot bot=new Robot();
                BufferedImage image=bot.createScreenCapture(rec);
                ImageIO.write(image,"jpeg",os);
                System.out.println("Image Sent");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String aerg[])throws Exception
    {
        new imagesender();
    }
}
```

**imagereciever.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class imagereciever extends JPanel
{
    static BufferedImage image;
    imagereciever()throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(5555);
        Socket soc=ss.accept();
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setContentPane(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //frame.setVisible(true);
        InputStream is=soc.getInputStream();
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                image=ImageIO.read(is);
                //this.repaint();
                ImageIO.write(image,"jpeg",new File("C:\\Users\\Arpit Jindal\\Desktop\\screenshot.jpeg"));
                System.out.println("Image Recieved");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {e.printStackTrace()}
        }
    }
    public static void main(String aerg[])throws Exception
    {
        new imagereciever();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
    }
}
```

**imagereciever.java** recieves one image and then gives this error infinite times and **imagesender.java** keeps on sending images:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1592)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1520)
at imagereciever.<init>(imagereciever.java:26)
at imagereciever.main(imagereciever.java:37)
```

Comment: You mean, something like [this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505406/java-tcp-can-only-retrieve-image-once/18509880#18509880)?

Comment: You're getting the exception because `image` is `null` when you try and write it, but since we don't have the server component, it's impossible to know why

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer the example you gave, solved my problem. I used ByteArrayOutputStream and now my image is not **null** anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example @MadProgrammer gave to me solved my problem. This is my new Code:-

**imagesender.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class imagesender
{
    imagesender()throws Exception
    {
        Socket soc=new Socket("127.0.0.1",5555);
        OutputStream os=soc.getOutputStream();
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                BufferedImage image=new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ImageIO.write(image,"png",baos);
                baos.close();
                ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(os);
                oos.writeObject(baos.size()+"");
                os.write(baos.toByteArray());
                //System.out.println("Image Sent");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String aerg[])throws Exception
    {
        new imagesender();
    }
```

}

**imagereciever.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
class imagereciever extends JPanel
{
    static BufferedImage image;
    static Socket soc;
    static InputStream is;
    imagereciever()throws Exception
    {
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(5555);
        soc=ss.accept();
        is=soc.getInputStream();
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setContentPane(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(is);
                int size=Integer.parseInt(ois.readObject().toString());
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream(size);
                int sizeread=0,bytesin=0;
                byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
                while(sizeread<size)
                {
                    bytesin=is.read(buffer);
                    sizeread+=bytesin;
                    baos.write(buffer,0,bytesin);
                }
                baos.close();
                ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
                image=ImageIO.read(bais);
                this.repaint();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String aerg[])throws Exception
    {
        new imagereciever();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your GUI completely ignores Swing threading rules, so I'm not surprised that it might be getting stuck. Suggestions:

- Use a SwingWorker to do long-running background tasks such as reading in images. In your case, perhaps a `SwingWorker<Void, BufferedImage>` is what you want so that you can pass the BufferedImage to the GUI via the publish/process method pair. The [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorial will tell you the details on how to use this tool.
- Don't draw with the paint method.
- Instead draw in the paintComponent method of a JPanel that is displayed in JFrame. Be sure to call the super's paintComponent method within your override.
- Stop to consider -- do you really need images transmitted in this way as you're passing in a lot of information, perhaps more than is needed? Better would be to pass a data model over the socket and then recreate a view with the data, if possible.
- Never blatantly ignore exceptions as your code is doing. At least catch the exception's stacktrace.

Comment: in above code i have turned off swing and i am simply running it on command line then it is only receiving one image.

Comment: ignore my swing, just focus on my query

Comment: @ArpitJindal: so you're likely getting an exception but will never know since you're completely ignoring all exceptions, a very foolish thing to do -- why are you not at least catching exceptions and printing the stacktrace?

Comment: @ArpitJindal: and if you do get multiple images, you look to be overwritomg the previous image with the new one.

Comment: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!" <--- this exception is coming infinite times when i am printing the variable e in **imagereciever.java**

Comment: Place `e.printStacktrace();` within your catch block and print the resultant message with your question, indicating which line(s) are involved in throwing the exception.